# Search through Tab Control for specific Tab Item based on a String value

Tags: c#, wpf, search, tabcontrol

I would like to know how to select a `tabItem` in a `tabControl` whose name matches a specific string value. I'm guessing that I will have to do some sort of search.

Here's a visual example:

```
string selectedTabItem = "TabItem";

//if there exists a Tab Item in this specific tab control
//with the above string as it's Name
//that Tab Item .IsSelected = true;
```

Comment: Its Name or its Header?

Comment: It's Name is what I'm looking for.

Comment: The Name cannot contain a space.

Comment: I updated my answer for you, have a look it should be correct syntax now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming that you create your tabs manually, and not via bindings, then this should work:

```
tabControl.SelectedItem = tabControl.Items.OfType<TabItem>().SingleOrDefault(n => n.Name == selectedTabItem);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach (TabPage t in myTabControl.TabPages)
{
  if t.Name.Equals("something") 
  {
     myTabControl.SelectedTab = t;
     break;
  }
}
```

Basically you can loop through each tab and and see if the name matches your string

a better way to do it in my opinion is:

```
if (myTabControl.TabPages.ContainsKey("something"))
            myTabControl.SelectedTab = mytabControl.TabPages["something"];
```

Comment: Does WPF have `TabPage`?

Comment: I believe it should, i found a containskey method as well, have a look at the updated answer.

Comment: WPF control ([System.Windows.Controls.TabControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.tabcontrol.aspx)) won't have `TabPages` nor `SelectedTab` and tabs won't be of `TabPage` type. It's WinForms.

Comment: what dkozi said then in his answer, sorry I don't have my pc with me to try and find you the correct answer, thought this might work, google didn't yield much.